# Y Axis Autoscale Per Each Facet

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe which I want to plot on plotly express. 
The dataframe is a time series from a name. see below example:

```
enter code here

index    name   data  
0       name1   [0,1...1500]
1       name2   [1501, 1502...3000]
2       name3   [3001, 3002...4500]
```

The situation is that as you see the data columns have different amplitudes.

Can I set an autoscale for each facet. 
For the moment they all share the same y range

[image: Plotly Express Line plot]

```
enter code here
fig1 = px.line(dfplot, x= 'time', y= 'data', line_group= 'Name', 
               hover_name= 'Name, facet_row= 'Name', width= 1600,
               height= 1600, color= 'Name')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can call `fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @nicolaskruchten this worked like wonders. 

One question I am slightly new to Plotly and have worked most of the time with matplotlib. 
I have been test riding for a couple of hours Plotly and seems really cool, but the documentation is really hard to find. 

Where can I find clarifications or better documentation than the typical search links that you get in google when you search "plotly express documentation". 

Or your answer comes from plotly library itself?

Comment: We have woven Plotly Express examples throughout the Plotly.py documentation which is located here: https://plot.ly/python :)